# How to create a queue user in oracle?

Tags: oracle, queue, oracle-aq

I have a QUEUE_OWNER schema that has some queues. When I connect the application to that data source everything works fine and the app can read the from the queues.

I want to create a _USER schema that has access to the queues so I can connect the app to it and not directly to the _OWNER schema.

This is what I tried:

```
BEGIN 
    
    FOR Q IN (SELECT * FROM ALL_QUEUES WHERE owner = 'AQ_OWNER') LOOP 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('queue = ' ||Q.NAME); 
    
    DBMS_AQADM.GRANT_QUEUE_PRIVILEGE('ALL','AQ_OWNER.'||Q.NAME ,'AQ_USER',FALSE); 
    END LOOP;
    
END;
```

but when I put a message in the queue nothing happens in the app.

Answer (score 0):

How about a little help of your DBA?

This is what my user `SCOTT` sees in `all_queues`:

```
SQL> select owner, name from all_queues;

OWNER                          NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
SYS                            SRVQUEUE
SYS                            SCHEDULER_FILEWATCHER_Q
SYS                            SCHEDULER$_EVENT_QUEUE
```

However, I'd like to see some other data. `SYS` almighty sees it all:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> select owner, name from dba_queues;

OWNER                          NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
SYS                            SYS$SERVICE_METRICS
SYS                            AQ$_SYS$SERVICE_METRICS_TAB_E
SYSTEM                         DEF$_AQERROR
SYSTEM                         AQ$_DEF$_AQERROR_E
SYSTEM                         DEF$_AQCALL
SYSTEM                         AQ$_DEF$_AQCALL_E
SYS                            AQ$_KUPC$DATAPUMP_QUETAB_E
<snip>
```

Still connected as `SYS`, I'll create a **view** which show data only for owner I choose (there's nothing much to choose in my XE database so I'll use `SYSTEM`-owned values). Then grant `select` privilege to `SCOTT`:

```
SQL> create or replace view v_dba_queues as
  2  select name
  3  from dba_queues
  4  where owner = 'SYSTEM';

View created.

SQL> grant select on v_dba_queues to scott;

Grant succeeded.
```

Back to `SCOTT`: to make my life simpler, I'll create a **synonym** first:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> create synonym v_dba_queues for sys.v_dba_queues;

Synonym created.
```

Finally:

```
SQL> select * from v_dba_queues;

NAME
------------------------------
DEF$_AQERROR
AQ$_DEF$_AQERROR_E
DEF$_AQCALL
AQ$_DEF$_AQCALL_E

SQL>
```

---

Basically, you'd do the same; it's just that your view would contain data for `owner = 'QUEUE_OWNER'`. See if it helps.